# Float imprecision occuring on NSString

Tags: ios, types, nsstring

I'm currently having a very strange issue. I'm running into the "float imprecision problem" when defining a number as an NSString. Here is an excerpt from my JSON file, which I am reading from my iOS application:

```
{"id":"804760","addtime":"1398886836","symbol":"UG","exchange":"NAS(USA)","shares":"71.00","cost":"0","in_price":"32.64","price":28.78,"rchange":-0.72,"rchange_p":-2.44,"a_open":"28.72","volume":"8K","a_low":"28.54","a_high":"29.44","pettm":"23.40","ps":"8.60","pb":"8.40","gain_p":"-11.83%","gain":-274.06,"comments":""}
```

I read this into an NSMutableArray, and then I want to display individual pieces of information. The code I use to do this is as follows:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(NSString *)json[indexPath.section][@"detail"][indexPath.row][@"price"]];
```

However, I'm getting the floating point precision error where there's a ton of extra decimal places that were not there in the original JSON output. This confuses me, because I specified the data type as NSString, so even though the string consists of all numbers and decimal points, shouldn't it still be treated as such?

What I am not understanding correctly, and why is this happening? By the way, the error is also resolved if I add quotation marks when creating the JSON output, such as `"a_high":"\"29.44\""`. I would prefer not to do this though.

Comment: Note that "price" is just about the only quantity in that JSON that's transmitted as a number rather than a string.  What you're seeing is perfectly normal for a free-formatted floating-point value.

Comment: I believe that NSDictionary will place all as NSObjects, so if your value has "", it's treated as an NSString, if not and it in numeric, it is handled as an NSNumber

Comment: @gro My bad, I meant NSMutableArray instead of NSDictionary. Does this still apply?

Comment: @HotLicks What exactly do you mean? There's a lot of other decimal numbers such as `pettm`, `ps`, `pb`, etc. I should also mention that these numbers display fine. I should probably also mention that the only fields that I'm having problems with display are `price` and `in_price`.

Comment: Not all decimal numbers can be expresses exactly in floating point numbers. This is especially true of numbers between integer values. The is  a basic number issue when converting between number bases, in this case base10 (most people) to base2 (the computer) and vice-versa. This shows up as small differences and based on the formation may show up or not. Suggestion: read up on floating point numbers WRT computers.

Comment: `,"in_price":"32.64","price":28.78,"rchange":-0.72,` -- do you notice something different about "price" vs "in_price"???  "in_price" has a string value, "price" has a numeric value, as does "rchange".  The numerics will translate into an NSNumber, not an NSString.

Comment: Unless you are doing something to cast them differently, then yes, I believe they are also added as NSObjects. You can test values with isKindOfClass to verify.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for pointing that out, I set all the values as strings using PHP `strval()` and that resolved the issue. If you could post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`,"in_price":"32.64","price":28.78,"rchange":-0.72,` -- do you notice something different about "price" vs "in_price"? "in_price" has a string value, "price" has a numeric value, as does "rchange". The numerics will translate into an NSNumber, not an NSString.